# Matrix Division in GLM

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, glm-math

I'm experimenting with OpenGL currently and I've come upon a situation where I want to find the 4x4 matrix `x` where `x * mat1 = mat2` (column major order, i think. where `x * mat1` means apply the transformations in `mat1`, then `x`.).

Naturally, I thought that the solution might be `x = mat2 / mat1`, so I tried it with glm. And it worked! The following snippet would output `true`.

```cpp
glm::mat4 mat1 = glm::translate(glm::vec3{1,2,3});
glm::mat4 mat2 = glm::scale(glm::vec3{-1,-2,-3});

glm::mat4 x = mat2 / mat1;
std::cout << ((x * mat1) == mat2) << std::endl;
```

But then, I realized that `mat1 * x != x * mat1`!
How does this make any sense? `mat2 / mat1` would be ambiguous! Is my solution of division satisfactory for finding x or are there any caveats? (Again, my goal is to have `x * mat1 = mat2`)

I came across this discussion too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228229/is-division-of-matrices-possible?newreg=c7fd79a48ae54ed694af1ee5f4646af7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as matrix division. However, scalar division is simply multiplying by the inverse of the scalar value. As such, one could (and GLM does) define "matrix division" to be the same thing: multiplying by the inverse.

So your `mat2 / mat1` is really `mat2 * glm::inverse(mat1)`.

As for commutativity, let's look at the algebra here. You start with this:

```
x * mat1 = mat2
```

And you want to solve for `x`. You therefore multiply both sides by a value that removes `mat1` from the left side of the equation. Namely, `glm::inverse(mat1)`.

*However*, because matrix multiplication is not commutative, you know that doing `glm::inverse(mat1) * (x * mat1)` does not actually get rid of the `mat1` on the left of the equation. Therefore, you must *right*-multiply by the inverse to get rid of the `mat1`.

And since algebraic transformations only work if you do the exact same operation to both sides, you must also right-multiply on the right side:

```
(x * mat1) * glm::inverse(mat1) = mat2 * glm::inverse(mat1)
```

So there is no ambiguity about the order; if you do them in the wrong order, you get the wrong answer.